# matching commas in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I've tested my regex with [Pythex](https://pythex.org/) and it works as it's supposed to:

The HTML:

```html
Something Very Important (SVI) 2013 Sercret Information, Big Company
Name (LBCN) Catalog Number BCN2013R18 and BSSN 3-55564-789-Y, was
developed as part of the SUP 2012 Something Task force was held in
conjunction with <a href="http://justaURL.com">*SEM    2013</a>, the second joint conference on study of
banana hand grenades and gorilla tactics (Association of Ape Warfare
Studies) interest groups BUDDY HOLLY and LION KING. It is comprised of
one hairy object containing 750 gross stories told in the voice of
Morgan Freeman and his trusty sidekick Michelle Bachman.
```

My regex:

```
,[\s\w()-]+,
```

When used with [Pythex](https://pythex.org/) it selects the area I'm looking for, which is between the 2 commas in the paragraph:

> Something Very Important (SVI) 2013 Sercret Information **, Big
>   Company Name (LBCN) Catalog Number BCN2013R18 and BSSN
>   3-55564-789-Y,** was developed as part of the SUP 2012 Something Task
>   force was held in conjunction with <a href="http://justaURL.com">*SEM 
>     2013</a>, the second joint
>   conference on study of banana hand grenades and gorilla tactics
>   (Association of Ape Warfare Studies) interest groups BUDDY HOLLY and
>   LION KING. It is comprised of one hairy object containing 750 gross
>   stories told in the voice of Morgan Freeman and his trusty sidekick
>   Michelle Bachman.

However when I use BeautifulSoup's text regex:

```
print HTML.body.p.find_all(text=re.compile('\,[\s\w()-]+\,'))
```

I'm returned this instead of the area between the commas:

```
[u'Something Very Important (SVI) 2013 Sercret Information, Big Company Name (LBCN) Catalog Number BCN2013R18 and BSSN 3-55564-789-Y, was developed as part of the SUP 2012 Something Task force was held in conjunction with ']
```

I've also tried escaping the commas but to no luck. Beautiful soup just wants to return the whole `<p>` instead of the regex that I specified. Also I noticed that it returns the paragraph up until that link in the middle. Is this a problem with how I'm using BeautifulSoup or is this a regex problem?

Comment: As an aside, it doesn't appear to be the *link* it stops at, but the *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup uses the regular expression to search for matching elements. That whole text node matches your search.

You still then have to extract the part you want; BeautifulSoup does not do this for you. You could just reuse your regex here:

```
expression = re.compile('\,[\s\w()-]+\,')
textnode = HTML.body.p.find_all(text=expression)
print expression.search(textnode).group(0)
```